# Ninject: resolve second level inner dependency

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm getting into Ninject. Simplifying my real scenario, I have a class A with property injection:

```
public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMasterViewModel>().To<IQMasterViewModel>();
    }
}

public class A
{
    [Inject]
    public IMasterViewModel _viewModel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public A()
    {
    }
}
```

And a class B that instantiate A via default constructor:

```
public class B
{
    public A a = new A();
}


Ninject.IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectBindings());
var b = kernel.Get<B>();
```

If I try to resolve class B using Ninject.kernell.Get() call the dependency of class A will not be injected into A instance.
Can anyone suggest what is the correct way to handle such injection if I can't change the way object A is instantiated?
Because in real scenario class B is a WPF Window and class A is a UserControl declared in XAML.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for A to have its dependencies injected it needs to be instantiated by Ninject.

When using IoC you should be passing in dependencies rather than instantiating in the class with `new`. Therefore you can fix this by passing A as a constructor argument to B instead of instantiating it yourself in the constructor.

```
public class B
{
    public A MyA;

    public B(A a)
    {
        MyA = a;
    }
}
```

Depending on how your classes are set up, you may need to create bindings or let them be self-bindable. I would suggest creating interfaces for A and B and binding these to the concrete types, as it makes the code much easier to test with a mocking framework.

Note that the binding you posted...

```
Bind<IMasterViewModel>().To<IQMasterViewModel>();
```

appears to be binding an interface to an interface rather than a concrete type, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Class A doesn't have its dependencies injected, because is instantiated by you, not by your container.

I believe this is more about how to implement MVVM properly. See frameworks like Caliburn micro or Prism how to do it.